# Ignore/map case in command prompt :edit fileName

Tags: neovim, command-line, normal-mode

I would like to use case-ignoring completion in the file arguments I pass to (n)vim in the internal command prompt:

1. For example, `:edit case<tab>` should suggest `caselower.txt` and `Caseupper.txt`.
2. Or `:edit some-<tab>` should offer completions including `some_underscore.txt` in addition to `some-dash.txt`)

I'm calling this completion suggestions **in the prompt line** (I'm not sure what else to search for in (n)vim `:help`, `:com[mands]` is not quite right.) I would like behavior equivalently to setting `completion-ignore-case` and `completion-map-case` in  bash/readline. (bash: `bind '[set ... on]'` .inputrc: `set [...] on`).

Can I set up this completion **ignore & map** case in vim? If so, how? (Interested for vi/vim/Neovim)

Comment: Could you tell us which OS your are using (Windows, MacOS, Linux)?

Comment: On Windows the completion is case insensitive like the file system is. But `-` and `_` are treated as different characters. Could I ask you why you would like completion to be case insensitive? Are you looking for some kind of fuzzy completion like in (`CtrlP`, `FZF` or `Clap`)?

Comment: I use macOS & Linux.

Comment: It seems - and _ are not case-insensitive matches in vim/nvim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim provides file completion based on the filesystem characteristics (i.e. case sensitive for Linux, case insensitive for Windows).

As Matt mention you can force case insensitiveness using:

```
set wildignorecase
```

It also provide completion based on wildcard (e.g. `?`, `*`)

But it doesn't provide fuzzy completion.

`:help wildoption`

```
Currently fuzzy matching based completion
is not supported for file and directory names and
instead wildcard expansion is used.
```

There are a number of plugin that helps user to find their files using some fuzzy logic the most famous are:

- [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)
- [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)
- [telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) for Neovim
- [clap](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-clap) my favorite for Windows

Comment: Thanks for the more extensive clarification of the limitations! :)

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Thanks for the feedback, @Matt also clarifed the `wildignorecase` flag.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I set up this completion ignore & map case in vim? If so, how?

Yes, `:set wildignorecase`